# Exclude rows when certain condition is met

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to exclude row id's 2,4,7,9 whenever a person "logged ON" an extra event (login) happened and stored in a table. We want to exclude those login events which occurred after 10 mins of "LoggedOn" event.

```
RowID     LoginDateTime         Activity
----------------------------------------    
1         2019-11-19 10:12 A.M  LoggedOn
**2**     2019-11-19 10:12 A.M  Login
3         2019-11-22 11:53 A.M  LoggedOn
**4**     2019-11-22 11:53 A.M  Login
5         2019-11-28 10:52 A.M  LoggedOn
6         2019-12-02 12:08 P.M  LoggedOn
**7**     2019-12-02 12:08 P.M  Login
8         2019-12-13 10:18 A.M  LoggedOn
**9**     2019-12-13 10:19 A.M  Login
10        2019-12-13 10:29 A.M  Login
11        2019-12-13 10:39 A.M  LoggedOff
```

Comment: can you post the query how you written for more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `LAG` here along with a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        LAG(LoginDateTime, 1, LoginDateTime) OVER (ORDER BY LoginDateTime) AS LoginDateTimeLag,
        LAG(Activity) OVER (ORDER BY LoginDateTime) As ActivityLag
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    RowID,
    LoginDateTime,
    Activity
FROM cte
WHERE
    ActivityLag <> 'LoggedOn' OR
    Activity <> 'Login' OR
    DATEDIFF(minute, LoginDateTimeLag, LoginDateTime) <= 10;
```

### Demo

Note: I use a default value for the `LoginDateTime` as the same column value itself.  This would ensure that, for the earliest record in the table, the `WHERE` clause would pass, and that record would be included in the result set.

Also note that your sample data is such that every record would be returned using the filtering logic you actually described in your question.  In the demo, I spaced out records 2, 4, 7, and 9, such that their logins were more than 10 minutes than the previous logged on records.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #temp(RowID int,LoginDateTime datetime,Activity varchar(15))
insert into #temp values  
(1      ,'2019-11-19 10:12','LoggedOn')
,(2  ,'2019-11-19 10:12','Login')
,(3      ,'2019-11-22 11:53','LoggedOn')
,(4  ,'2019-11-22 11:53','Login')
,(5      ,'2019-11-28 10:52','LoggedOn')
,(6      ,'2019-12-02 12:08','LoggedOn')
,(7  ,'2019-12-02 12:08','Login')
,(8      ,'2019-12-13 10:18','LoggedOn')
,(9  ,'2019-12-13 10:19','Login')
,(10     ,'2019-12-13 10:29','Login')
,(11     ,'2019-12-13 10:39','LoggedOff')

;With CTE as
(
select t.RowID from #temp t
cross apply(select top 1 RowID from #temp t1 where t1.Activity='LoggedOn' 
and datediff(minute,t1.LoginDateTime,t.LoginDateTime)<10
order by t1.LoginDateTime)ca
where  t.Activity='Login' 
)
select * from #temp t
where not exists(select 1 from CTE c where t.rowid=c.rowid)

drop table #temp
```